# XPath find text in any text node

Tags: xpath

I am trying to find a certain text in any text node in a document, so far my statement looks like this:

```
doc.xpath("//text() = 'Alliance Consulting'") do |node|
  ...
end
```

This obviously does not work, can anyone suggest a better alternative?

Comment: Are you sure you want to find the text node? I think it's more likely that you really want to find the element containing the text node. I would suggest `//*[. = 'Alliance Consulting']`

Comment: @Michael Kay: I agree that it's better not to select text nodes (particulary in mixed content data model like XHTML). But I would use `//*[. = 'Alliance Consulting'][not(* = 'Alliance Consulting')]` to select the inner most elements with such string value.

Comment: Your question might be more valuable if you removed the Ruby code. Not everyone will recognize it, and it doesn't seem relevant to your question.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This expression `//text() = 'Alliance Consulting'` evals to a boolean.

In case of this test sample:

```
<r>
    <t>Alliance Consulting</t>
    <s>
        <p>Test string
            <f>Alliance Consulting</f>
        </p>
    </s>
    <z>
        Alliance Consulting
        <y>
            Other string
        </y>
    </z>
</r>
```

It will return `true` of course.

Expression you need should evaluate to node-set, so use:

```
//text()[. = 'Alliance Consulting']
```

E.g. expression:

```
count(//text()[normalize-space() = 'Alliance Consulting'])
```

against the above document will return `3`.

To select text nodes which contain `'Alliance Consulting'` in the whole string value (e.g. `'Alliance Consulting provides great services'`) use:

```
//text()[contains(.,'Alliance Consulting')]
```

Do note that **adjacent** text nodes should become one after parser gets to the document.

Comment: This seems to return an object which only contains a length property, no nodes. How does one get the parent nodes of the found text?

Comment: @geoidesic this should work: //*[contains(text(), 'Alliance Consulting')]