# How to compute xpath from text in capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, capybara

I am trying to compute xpath of an element based on its text content. Is there a way?

so far I need to have the tag to compute the xpath

```
//a[contains(., 'text to be found')]
```

I need some xpath without the tag. something like the following.

```
//*[contains(., 'text to be found')]
```

This doesn't work

Comment: It seems to be related to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074469/xpath-find-text-in-any-text-node).

Comment: @Dougui That gets the text inside the node. I need to select the node.

Comment: The second XPath, with `*`, should work. The OP might have something else going on. And I always use `text()` never `.`.

Comment: @Phlip when I tried //*[contains(text(), 'text to be found')] it took infinitely long time to fetch the node. so settled for the format I have mentioned as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it work with

```
//*[. = 'text to be found']
```

@Dougui Thank you for the correct direction :)