# Search for string anywhere within SimpleXML object

Tags: php, simplexml

Is it possible to search for text within an SimpleXML object directly, or does it need to be converted to a string first?

Comment: Why you can't just make another SimpleXML object for the error xml? and the parse the text content of the datafeed element.

Comment: The error xml has the same filename. But even if it didn't, my question is still what php code will allow me to search for 'Code 1' in that SimpleXML object as part of my if statement.

Comment: Have you tried converting the object(s) to string?

Comment: Thanks adrian7 - I wondered whether there was a way of doing it directly, that is all.

Comment: You can perform xpath searches for text containing a string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074469/xpath-find-text-in-any-text-node

Comment: Your question in this simplified form is not really clear to me. If I search a string I somehow will always need to convert what I search to a string as well - otherwise I could not compare the string I search for. In any case, the answer to your question is: Yes, it is possible.