# Parsing an XML document of text anywhere

Tags: java, xml

For an XML document, I want to be able to find all the elements/nodes that have a certain text 'abc' in it. This text will be primarily found in the attributes (property name='abc'). The thing is the attribute name will not be known beforehand so I cannot parse the exact attribute name. Is there any way to handle this easily?

I am using XPath, but I can only solve this problem if I know what the attribute name is. I want to find elements that have the text 'abc' without knowing the attributes and such.

Comment: Hi, please check the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074469/xpath-find-text-in-any-text-node

Comment: this is not answering my question; i basically want to find all attributes that have a certain value. not the actual text field - i tried that solution already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More precise XPath expression can point to attribute values only

```
//*[@*='abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting my answer here:

```
//*[text()='some_abc_text']
```

will get you whole node with its text.